# How to exclude page in pages module

Tags: pages, page-specific-settings

Site has page with url

http://example.com/mywpsite/mypage

Pinboard theme is used.

Pages module shows this in left sidebar.
How to remove it from this?
Pages module setting contain field

excluded page ids

I put mypage to it but page is still shown in page list.
I havent found any other page id in wordpress for this page.

**Update**

Pages confing menu can reached as follows (texts translated to english):

In admin panel click

Appearance
Modules

and look into "Sidebar left".

It contains word Pages below.
After that is Change link
After that config menu appears containing field Jäta välaj - "Excluded page ids, separated by comma".
There is page name "viga" entered but page viga still appears in list. I use page name as post link setting.
For posts I can click in get link button and see number which is probably post id. For page there is no such setting.

[image: pages config]

Comment: What do you mean by "pages module"?

Comment: I updated question